# SQL Server bulk insert using variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

How to do a bulk insert from a variable ?

I have a `Grades` table in my database:

```
PersonId        Marks
---------------------
1                10 
2                15 
3                13 
4                11
```

and I have this variable

```
PersonID varchar = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20"
Marks varchar = "0,1,2,5,8,9,4,6,7,3,5,2,7,1,9,4,0,2,5,0"
```

I want to insert this value to the grade table using bulk insert and I want to compare the mark between the table and the var if its different I will replace it by the new mark

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly your question is. What did you try? What problem you have?

Comment: @BalakrishnaD

I have this variable :

PersonID varchar = ‘1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20’ 
Marks varchar = ’0,1,2,5,8,9,4,6,7,3,5,2,7,1,9,4,0,2,5,0’

and I want to insert this  values to table using bulk insert

Comment: @Moh can you please clarrify what you excatly want? (and at this to your question)

Comment: @moh can you update your question with this information and maybe add the table structure. I really helps if you create clear question with enough information. Don't paste the new information in the comments but add it to you question

Comment: @B.Termeer can you check it now

Comment: BULK INSERT only inserts - you cannot compare and insert or update - it's just a very fast **insert only** operation

Comment: @marc_s Ok how can i do the bulk in this case ?

Comment: @B.Termeer

How can we do a bulk insert from variable of type table ?

Comment: @BalakrishnaD

How can we do a bulk insert from variable of type table ?

Comment: @moh please create a new question on how to do this and please avoid doinjg this in comments. Please take a look on how to ask correct question at this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. to answer your question. i dont use bulk inserts so i dont know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to split your data using `XML` Method & then you could Insert the Data in `Table Variable` by which you could update the `Grade` Table as New Marks available in `Table Variable` :-

```
DECLARE @ID NVARCHAR(300)= '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20';
DECLARE @Marks NVARCHAR(300)= '0,1,2,5,8,9,4,6,7,3,5,2,7,1,9,4,0,2,5,0';
DECLARE @StudentsMark TABLE
(id    NVARCHAR(300),
 marks NVARCHAR(300)
); 

;WITH CTE
     AS (
     SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') id,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY
                             (
                                 SELECT NULL
                             )) RN
     FROM
     (
         SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@ID, ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String
     ) AS A
     CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(a)),
     CTE1
     AS (
     SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') marks,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY
                             (
                                 SELECT NULL
                             )) RN
     FROM
     (
         SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@Marks, ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String
     ) AS A
     CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(a))
     INSERT INTO @StudentsMark
            SELECT C.id,
                   C1.marks
            FROM CTE C
                 LEFT JOIN CTE1 C1 ON C1.RN = C.RN;
UPDATE G
  SET
      G.Marks = M.marks
FROM grades G
     INNER JOIN @StudentsMark M ON G.PersonId = M.id;
SELECT *
FROM grades;
```

**Result :**

```
PersonId    Marks
1           0
2           1
3           2
4           5
```

Comment: Can we do bulk insert from array ?

Comment: @Moh you could ask question with your new requirement or show sample data.

Comment: How can we do a bulk insert from variable of type table ?

Comment: @Moh in normal way from one table to other.

Comment: @Moh wht you want, in above u have one var from which u wanted to update the marks which was correct as u,  then now ?

Comment: i want to insert marks from variable of type table into the original marks table by using the bulk